# как может образоваться очередь к устройствам ввода-вывода при невытесняющей многозадачности?

Tags: железо, процессор, внешние-устройства

В вытесняющей понятно: процесс исполняется, потом ему бац и понадобился принтер. Начинает исполняться другой процесс. Ему вдруг тоже понадобился принтер. А тот первый еще не закончил печатать.. второй встает в очередь к принтеру.

А в невытесняющей откуда очереди? Исполняется процесс, ну понадобился ему принтер, он и будет печатать, другой процесс не начнет исполняться, пока он печатает.

**UPD:** Я слышал что при невытесняющей многозадачности процесс может уступить процессор, когда он закончил выполнение или когда ему нужен ресурс, который сейчас недоступен. Но как он может быть недоступен? 
Будет рассматривать  с первого процесса. Вот занял первый процесс в текущем сеансе процессор. Понадобилось ему устройству. Как оно может быть недоступно? Кем занято? Процесс то первый. Значит он и будет печатать, никому не отдавая процессор. Потом он закончился, пришел второй процесс... и для него справедливы все те же рассуждения что и для первого, разве нет?

Comment: При невытесянющей многозадачности не происходит насильного прерывания процесса, во время выполнения расчетных задач. Когда процессу необходим ввод-вывод (например, принтер) то процесс будет переключен ОС т.к. текущий процесс будет ожидать ответа внешнего устройста (принтера) и как раз в этот момент другой задаче так же захочется печатать

Comment: @Mike, видимо я это плохо понимаю, и не до конца раскрыл свое понимание в вопросе. Поэтому обновил вопрос. Скажите пожалуйста, в чем не прав?

Comment: У Вас абстрактный вопрос, т.е. "как все это должно  в принципе работать" или Вы все же говорите о каких-то конкретных реализациях?

Answer (score 2):

При невытесянющей многозадачности не происходит насильного прерывания процесса, во время выполнения расчетных задач. Когда процессу необходим ввод-вывод (например, принтер) то процесс будет переключен ОС т.к. текущий процесс будет ожидать ответа внешнего устройста (принтера) и как раз в этот момент другой задаче так же захочется печатать.

В общем виде ввод-вывод работает независимо от процессора. Процессор не занят например печатью каждого отдельного символа. Он отправляет принтеру блок данных (размером возможно несколько страниц) и принтер печатает. В это время центральный процессор свободен и может выполнять другую работу. Либо вызывающий процесс использует это время самостоятельно, либо ОС использует его для выполнения другого процесса.

Причем весь ввод-вывод работает подобным образом. Процесс захотел прочитать с диска. ОС отправляет диску команду чтения и настраивает DMA (устройство прямого доступа к памяти) на передачу данных от диска в нужную область ОЗУ. После этого процессор опять же совершенно свободен до тех пор, пока диск не закончит операцию. Причем обычно процессу, который решил получить с диска данные совершенно нечего делать пока данные готовятся, поэтому ОС переключает задачу и дает работать другому процессу. Другой процесс так же может захотеть обратится к тому же диску и тогда он будет поставлен в очередь т.к. диск и канал DMA в это время уже заняты.